# Unable to Create a Node with Label as a string parameter from a Function - in Neo4JClient

Tags: c#, parameter-passing, neo4jclient

Im using Neo4JClient To populate the Nodes in a Neo4JDB.

I have a Function that is invoked to create Nodes and Label them as well.
The First Parameter is the Label, and the Second Parameter is the node attribute

```
 function CreateConcpet( String sLabelString, String sDataSpaceName)
 {
     var newConcept = new Concept {DataSpace=sDataSpaceName};

     client.Cypher
         .Create("(concept:{labelstring} {ParamnewConcept})")
         .WithParam("ParamnewConcept",newConcept)
         .WithParam("labelstring",sLabelString)
         .ExecuteWithoutResults();
 }
```

This uses the Parameter to Substitute for the Label.

This does not work. From the various posts, I understand that WithParam does not work for Labels.

If the dreaded ExecuteCypher is the only way, can someone help me with a code snippet, that executes a string as query. I cannot find a code snippet, while the documentation gives the call, Im unable to find a sample which creates the query object and executes the String Query.

Answer (score 0):

You can't parametize things that will affect the compiled query plan. Labels are used in the query plan, thus, no parameters.

This is a general restriction with how parameters work in Neo4j, not just Neo4jClient.

Comment: Thanks Tatham Oddie, I could understand that from your previous posts. Can you please help me with a code snippet on how to execute a CypherQuery from a String formed for this purpose. I got this from the doc ((IRawGraphClient)client).ExecuteCypher(query). A piece of c# code that uses this from a string containing the CypherQuery would be greatly useful.

Comment: I tried the following: String qry="";  qry="Create n:Person";
GraphClient client=new GraphClient(new Uri("http://localhost:7474/db/data"));
client.Connect();
var results = ((IRawGraphClient)client).ExecuteGetCypherResults(new CypherQuery(qry,null, Neo4jClient.Cypher.CypherResultMode.Projection));   When executing  I get the following error : Compiler Error Message: CS0411: The type arguments for method 'Neo4jClient.IRawGraphClient.ExecuteGetCypherResults<TResult>(Neo4jClient.Cypher.CypherQuery)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

I had the very same problem which was (after much mashing of teeth) easily solved ...

I had two types of nodes, Person and Union.  These two lines labeled them

```
MATCH (n) where n.surname >' ' SET n :Person

MATCH (n) where n.surname is null SET n :Union
```

This was dependent on the two node types having different metadata which distinguished them.